# Can't Resolve 'fs' While Using Handlebars in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, handlebars.js

There are many posts about this issue, but none of them offer a solution to this issue.  I'm attempting to use Handlebars in my React app to generate a blog card.  However, when I run `npm run start` on my frontend, I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/handlebars/lib/index.js 15:11-24

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/.../Documents/App/App-Name/client/node_modules/handlebars/lib'
```

If it helps, here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://app-url.com",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.11",
    "@cloudinary/react": "^1.11.2",
    "@cloudinary/url-gen": "^1.9.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.15",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.35.0",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.8.1",
    "cloudinary-video-player": "^1.9.9",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}
```

Could someone please assist?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Browser builds in the npm-package](https://handlebarsjs.com/installation/#browser-builds-in-the-npm-package)